# Instrumentation Amplifier Gain set resistors

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

We are looking for Instrumentation Amplifiers for an application.  At this stage, we have decided a certain gain value for our Instrumentation Amplifier. The datasheet of the product mentions the very precise value of gain resistors to attain certain gain value. We haven't ordered the products yet as I am confused about whether we will be able to acquire the gain resistors ourselves (from some other manufactures) or they will come with the Instrumentation Amplifier package we will order?  Because these gain resistor values for certain gain sets are very precise which are difficult to get from manufactures. I am attaching the screenshot of AD8237 gain resistors from the datasheet as a reference.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8237.pdf

[image: AD8237 Instrumentation Amp gain set resistor values]

Comment: All of the resistor values listed are bog standard E96 (1% tolerance) resistor values, which are easily available.

Comment: [Where do I buy resistors from](https://www.google.com/search?q=where+do+I+buy+resistors+from&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908&oq=where+do+I+buy+resistors+from&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.7504j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: More important is what gain and tolerance do you need and why can't you achieve that with multiple std resistors in stock?  The gain is 1+ R2/R1.. The absolute values can change.

Answer (score 1):

The resistors are external, so you have to solder them on PCB and they are not part of IA. The resistors in the table are standard resistors, it shouldn't be a problem to get it from same distributor that will sell you the AI.

[Example distributor](https://eu.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Resistors/Film-Resistors/_/N-7gz3w?P=1yzeg0gZ1z0vnvfZ1z0vpm5Z1z0srtsZ1z0we4uZ1z0wljo) 481 hits for 95.3kohm